# Hadoop installation on Ubuntu

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-14.04

Can anybody provide me with the commands to install Hadoop 2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04?
I have checked various sites but they all seem to have different procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully installed it using [this](http://bigdatahandler.com/hadoop-hdfs/installing-single-node-hadoop-2-2-0-on-ubuntu/) step-by-step guide (in my case it was on 14.10, but I doubt there will be any difference)

Here is a important part:

```
wget http://apache.mirrors.pair.com/hadoop/common/stable2/hadoop-
2.2..tar.gz
tar –xvzf hadoop-2.2.0.tar.gz
mv hadoop-2.2.0 hadoop
sudo mv hadoop /usr/local/
sudo chown -R hduser:hadoop Hadoop
```

You can further configure it for your convenience, choose interface etc.

Hope this helps

Comment: the link you added is not exist